# How to import ngFor in angular 2 using Javascript?

Tags: angular

I am trying a small sample for displaying list using angular 2 beta
Here is app.component.js file

```
(function(app) {
app.AppComponent = ng.core
.Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:'<p>My name: {{ myName }}</p>' +
            '<p>Friends:</p>' +
                '<ul>' +
                '<li *ng-for="#name of names">{{ name }}</li>' +
                '</ul>',
directives: [angular.NgFor]
})
.Class({
  constructor: function() {
      this.myName = 'Peter';
      this.names = ["Aarav", "Martín", "Shannon", "Ariana", "Kai"];
  }
});
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

I am getting following error

Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Here is the HTML file

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
<script src='app/app.component.js'></script>
<script src='app/boot.js'></script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Is the syntax used here wrong?
I tried from angular sample page on their official site

Comment: You're using `ng` and `angular`, you should stick to the one that's working : `ng`. Besides that there's no need to add `NgFor` as a directive anymore, but if you want to you should use `ng.common.NgFor`. And the last thing is the [change in the template syntax](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/migration/kebab-case.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eric said in its comment, there is no need anymore to include core directives into your component.

Your mistake is the use of `ng-for`. The name of the directive is `ngFor`:

```
template: `
  <p>My name: {{ myName }}</p>
  <p>Friends:</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#name of names">{{ name }}</li>
  </ul>
`
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: If you use: template: `  ` you won't need the +'s

Comment: Yes, you definitely right! Thanks very much for pointing this out. I updated my answer...